404 Error ONLY When Accessing API via Subdomain on APN telefonica.es
I have a web application setup with the following infrastructure, and I'm encountering an issue that I hope you can help me resolve. Here is an overview of my setup:
Infrastructure Details:
The frontend of my web application is hosted on a subdomain provided by a hosting service.
The API (built with FastAPI) is hosted on a different subdomain (same hosting service).
The API is running on an Amazon EC2 instance using Uvicorn.
DNS and Server Configuration:
I have set up an A record for the backend subdomain that points to the public IP address of the EC2 instance.
On the EC2 instance, I am using Apache to:
Redirect HTTP traffic (port 80) to HTTPS (port 443).
Redirect HTTPS traffic (port 443) to port 8000, where Uvicorn is running.
Problem:
This setup works as expected in most cases. However, when clients use the telefonica.es APN, they receive a 404 error when trying to access the API. This apn is behind CG-NAT (don't know what this mean, but could be important)
Since this is my first time setting up networking infrastructure, I may have overlooked some best practices or configuration nuances.
I might not have explained everything in detail, so feel free to ask any clarifying questions.
Any help or pointers on what could be causing the 404 error specifically for clients using the telefonica.es APN would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
